# How can I support println in a class?

Tags: java, println

What does my own made class need to support in order for `println()` to print it? For example, I have:

```
public class A {
...
}
```

What methods should class `A` have to make this code work? Maybe something like this:

```
public static void main() {
    A a = new A();
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

I have a guess that the `toString()` method must be overloaded. Am I right? Is this enough?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can print any Object using [`System.out.println(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29). This overloaded version of println will print out `toString` representation of your object. If you want to customize what will be printed out, you must override the [`Object#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method, for example:

```
public class A {
    private String foo;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // When you print out instance of A, value of its foo
        // field will be printed out
        return foo;
    }
}
```

If you don't override the `Object#toString()` method, default implementation from `Object` class will be used, which has this form (class name and the hexidecimal representation of the instance hash code):

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

**Bonus:** if you need to create `toString()` implementation from multiple fields, there are tools to make it easier. For instance [`ToStringBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html) from Commons Lang. Or some Java IDEs like IntelliJ IDEA even offer to generate `toString` for you based on the class' fields.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide an override of [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method for this:

```
public class A {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A";
    }
}
```

> The method returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object.

Answer (score 0):

You need implement `toString()` method. Everything you return from it will be printed.